# How to get post_id from order_id in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to get post_id in wordpress from woocommerce order id or order number.

```
global $woocommerce, $post;

$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);

//to escape # from order id 

$order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number()));
```

with this code i am getting order id from post id. I have to reverse this and get post id from order id.

Comment: Check out this [url](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97176/get-product-id-from-order-id-in-woocommerce)

Answer (score 2):

you do realize that an order may contain 1 or more post id right?

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    //$product_name = $item['name'];
    //$product_id = $item['product_id']; // post id
    //$product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
$post_id = get_post($order_id)->ID;
```